# Query regarding traceroute and ping

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

While executing the `traceroute` command, why does the route to same host change at different times of the day?

Why does `traceroute` not find complete paths to some hosts?

Is it possible to find the route to certain hosts which fail to respond with the `ping` command?

Answer (score 3):

That's just how the internet works, I am afraid.

Routes can vary in the Internet as the paths are redundant, there are routers/firewalls along the way blocking things for security reasons and even hosts can refuse ICMP packets (pings).

As for the path(s), it is not even guaranteed the packets of a whole TCP transaction with go through the same path.

You can do as pretty much a traceroute based in TCP or UDP packets besides ICMP, if ICMP is being blocked.

For instance:

```
sudo tcptraceroute www.cnn.com 80
```

See [How to: Running a TCP Traceroute](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227989007-How-to-Running-a-TCP-Traceroute)

Comment: off-topic here: get the book TCP/IP illustrated vol I.- the protocols from Stevens

Comment: "doubts" is an odd word choice there.   quirks, maybe.  or possibly "That's just how the internet works".